# Advice cleaning up Jquery code and showing hidden element after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created an animation where a child divs moves onto its parent. The animation is exactly what I need, however there are a few issues I would appreciate some advice on.

- The parent div has  hidden text that I would like to show when the animation is complete and I am having trouble putting the code in.
- Due to the text, the child div does not cover its parent completely. It works when I move the text into the child, but I would like to keep it in the parent.
- jS is not my native language so I still struggle with "this", OOJS, and keeping it DRY. I have four other similar set-ups in the  div class "container_for_set_ups". I want to be able to have the same animation effects on the other set-ups that are only in this larger div. I only know how to achieve this by repeating everything with different selectors, but that would be ugly.

This is the current jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".parent_box").hover(function(){
    $(".child_box").animate({"top": '0px',"left": '0px'},500,function(){
        $(".child_box").css({"opacity": "0.4" }); 
    });
  },
function(){ $(".child_box").animate({"top": '50px',"left": '50px'},500,function(){
        $(".child_box").css({"opacity": "1" });        
    });
 });

});
```

Here is the link to my little project: http://jsfiddle.net/yLqEY/4/

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the position on $(".child_box") to absolute and set the position on .parent_box to relative and then change the .parent_box p visibility to visible like this
JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".parent_box").hover(function(){
    //$(".child_box",this) will select only the actual child to work with multiple divs 
    $(".child_box",this).animate({"top": '0px',"left": '0px'},500,function(){
        $(this).css({"opacity": "0.4" }).prev().css("visibility","visible"); //show p text
    });
  },
  function(){ $(".child_box",this).animate({"top": '50px',"left": '50px'},500,function(){
        $(this).css({"opacity": "1" }).prev().css("visibility","hidden"); //return to hidden      
    });
 });  
});
```

CSS

```
.parent_box{
    position:relative;//add this line
}

.child_box{
    position: absolute;//add this line   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLqEY/6/

Comment: Thanks Abraham. This looks great and the last part was partially answered. I updated the html to show how the divs should be placed in the DOM. This breaks the jS since I need the divs to be different names. http://jsfiddle.net/yLqEY/8/

Comment: if you want to use diferent class names just add another class like this [http://jsfiddle.net/yLqEY/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/yLqEY/9/)

Comment: .parent and .child make the js work and you can use another class for some other css rules

Comment: Very awesome. Thanks for keeping with this to the end :)

Answer (score 1):

For your animation issue, your animating box is relative and your text is too. So it's being spaced appropriately below the text.

Change things to the following:

```
.parent_box{
  position: relative;
}

.child_box{
  position: absolute;
}
```

For the text displaying after the animation I would swap `visibility:hidden;` with `display: none;` and then update your JS below:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".parent_box").hover(function(){
        $(".child_box").animate({"top": '0px',"left": '0px'},500,function(){
            $(".child_box").css({"opacity": "0.4" });
            $('.parent_box p').show(); 
        });
      },
   function(){ $(".child_box").animate({"top": '50px',"left": '50px'},500,function(){
            $(".child_box").css({"opacity": "1" });
            $('.parent_box p').hide();
        });
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your position of p tag to absolute.

```
.parent_box p{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yLqEY/5/

Comment: Yay! That solves the moving and the code looks much better. Part three of the question still needs a little help- I have 3 other divs that are within the larger div(container for set-ups), any advice on how to get the animation on the other divs when I hover over them without duplicating code? I also only want the divs within "container_for_set_ups" to have this animation feature. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, each set-up of nested squares has a different class name. That is why the current situation wont work.